# Get text from web site

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to get the content of a web site and paste it onto a excel sheet.

Before trying to code something in VBA I was simply doing **"Control + A"** (to select ALL the content from the page I want), **"Control + C"** (to copy it to the clipboard) and then **"Control + V"** (to paste it in my sheet).

This sort of information is all I want, this is all I need.

The way I will manipulate the data is another story and it's all working just fine.

I need no other way to get information from the web site then the one that **"Control + A"** and  **"Control + C"** provides me.

That being said, this is the code I've found and which I'm trying to make it work:

```
Sub Get_Text_From_Page()

   Dim sURL As String

   sURL = "https://www.microsoft.com"

   Dim IE As Object
   Set IE = New InternetExplorer

   With IE
       .Visible = True
       .navigate (sURL)
       While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
       Range("A1").Value = .Document.body.innerText
   End With

End Sub
```

This opens a browser and then it crashes with an Automation Error at `"While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend".`

I've found a few code examples in many places, but they all crash with that `Busy` or `ReadyState` stuff...

Edit: Not sure if this is gonna take me anywhere, but I've just found something about `SendKeys "^a"` and then `SendKeys "^c"`.

Comment: IE is EOL. Search for vba and web-scraping https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba+web

Answer (score 0):

You could try to refer to the code example below.

It will launch the IE browser. Open the website. After the site gets loaded, it will select all the content, copy it, and paste it to sheet1 in Excel.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim IE As Object

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("A1").Select

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
       
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://microsoft.com"
    
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
       
    IE.ExecWB 17, 0
    IE.ExecWB 12, 2
    
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        
    IE.Quit

End Sub
```

You could try it and let us know whether it works for you.

If you have some questions about the code, please let me know about it.